# Insert emojies from one emoji-picker to two diffrent textareas

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have two textareas in a single page, I'm trying to insert an emoji to textarea on which the cursor is on from one emoji-pickers, right now I abled to do this with two emoji-picker. How to change it to only one? It stop working if i change :value="value" to :value="value1" for example.

TextareaEmojiPicker.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="textarea-emoji-picker"> 
    <picker
      set="messenger"
      v-show="showEmojiPicker"
      emoji="wave"
      @select="addEmoji"
    />
    <span
      class="emoji-trigger"
      :class="{ 'triggered': showEmojiPicker }"
      @mousedown.prevent="toggleEmojiPicker"
    >
      <svg
        style="width:20px;height:20px"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      >
        <path fill="#888888" d="M20,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,4A8,8 0 0,0 4,12A8,8 0 0,0 12,20A8,8 0 0,0 20,12M22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12M10,9.5C10,10.3 9.3,11 8.5,11C7.7,11 7,10.3 7,9.5C7,8.7 7.7,8 8.5,8C9.3,8 10,8.7 10,9.5M17,9.5C17,10.3 16.3,11 15.5,11C14.7,11 14,10.3 14,9.5C14,8.7 14.7,8 15.5,8C16.3,8 17,8.7 17,9.5M12,17.23C10.25,17.23 8.71,16.5 7.81,15.42L9.23,14C9.68,14.72 10.75,15.23 12,15.23C13.25,15.23 14.32,14.72 14.77,14L16.19,15.42C15.29,16.5 13.75,17.23 12,17.23Z" />
      </svg>
    </span>

    <textarea
      placeholder="Body"
      ref="textarea"
      class="textarea"
      :value="value"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    >
    </textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Picker } from 'emoji-mart-vue'

export default {
  components: { Picker },

   props: {
      value: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      },
      value1: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      },
    },

  //props: ['value', 'value1'],

  data () {
    return {
      showEmojiPicker: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleEmojiPicker () {
      this.showEmojiPicker = !this.showEmojiPicker
    },

    addEmoji (emoji) {
      const textarea = this.$refs.textarea
      const cursorPosition = textarea.selectionEnd
      const start = this.value.substring(0, textarea.selectionStart)
      const end = this.value.substring(textarea.selectionStart)
      const text = start + emoji.native + end
      this.$emit('input', text)
      textarea.focus()
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        textarea.selectionEnd = cursorPosition + emoji.native.length
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Articles.vue

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="addArticle" class="mb-3" style="padding-top:25px;">
  <textarea-emoji-picker
    v-model="article.title"
  />

  <textarea-emoji-picker
    v-model="article.body"
  />

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Publish</button>
</form>
</template>
```